# Please create for the contractate ABI encoded constructor argument to verify an Ehtereum contract on etherscan.io?

Tags: etherscan

Please create for the contractate ABI encoded constructor argument to verify an Ehtereum contract on etherscan.io?
contract - https://etherscan.io/address/0x7af7470Aa8e4601f4174402DEd7917Fb046aE3D2